# How to create a custom login class in cloudmine?

Tags: android, ios, cloud

I'm new to Cloudmine and want to create new users from my iOS app with following key value pairs

```
{
  "email" : ""
  "password" : ""
  "role" : "customer/merchant"
  "platform" : "android/ios"
}
```

but the available class CMUser allows only following key value pairs

```
{
"email": ""
"password": ""
"username" : ""
}
```

https://cloudmine.io/docs/#/ios#create-user

and allows me to create a user with

```
CMUser *user = [[CMUser alloc] initWithEmail:@"userName" andPassword:@"password"];
```

If someone could guide me on how to achieve this I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom class for Users in cloudmine, instead you should extend the CMUser class and then save other properties using user.saveProfile() method.

Please refer to [Update User Profiles](https://cloudmine.io/docs/#/android_and_java#update-user-profiles) of cloudmine documentation